# Creating a trigger generating ID column value before insert when new tables is created

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

When a table create in schema (MYSCHEMA), I need to create a trigger that generate a ID column (from sequence) before insert in each created table..
How can I realize this?

I know, how I can realize generation of ID column through trigger and sequence, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR1
  BEFORE INSERT ON TB1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT SQ1.nextval
    INTO :new.primary_key_column
    FROM dual;
END;
```

But I don't know, how I can use `AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA` trigger to create trigger after `CREATE TABLE` in my schema with `BEFORE INSERT`...

I've written this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER /*APPROOT*/after_create_table_trigger
AFTER CREATE ON APPROOT.SCHEMA
DECLARE 
TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
IF ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
SELECT ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME INTO TABLE_NAME FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
('CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER id_table_gen
  BEFORE INSERT ON ' || TABLE_NAME ||
  ' FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    SELECT APPROOT.AE_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL
     INTO :new.ID
     FROM dual;
   END;');
END IF;
END;
/
```

Then I've created test table with one field - ID, but my trigger doesn't work...
I think the reason is wrong using of event attribute function ora_dict_obj_name.

Could somebody give me advice about this?

Thank you.

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and hit the `{}` button - it makes it readable and adds syntax highlighting.

Comment: How can your schema trigger tell which column of the new table should be "bound" to the sequence?

Comment: primary_key_column name = ID in all new tables!

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? what error? i see you have forgotten to prefix the table name with `APPROOT.` which will probably cause a `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` when you create a table.

Comment: Hm, thank you for advice!.. My mistake was that I've written this trigger not in SYS schema (but in schema with DBA role). Yes, it's working!

Comment: Could you explain which permissions need to create this trigger in not SYS schema? Or it can't? When I've created this trigger in developer's schema (I have grant create trigger), I recieved this error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ora-01031 insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at line 4... Thank you, DazzaL!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works ok if i put the schema name in the DDL.

```
SQL> connect sys/test as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_create_table_trigger
  2  AFTER CREATE ON TEST.SCHEMA
  3  DECLARE
  4  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
  5  BEGIN
  6  IF ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
  7  SELECT ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME INTO TABLE_NAME FROM DUAL;
  8  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  9  ('CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ID_TABLE_GEN
 10    BEFORE INSERT ON TEST.' || TABLE_NAME ||
 11    ' FOR EACH ROW
 12     BEGIN
 13      SELECT TEST.AE_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL
 14       INTO :new.ID
 15       FROM dual;
 16     END;');
 17  END IF;
 18  END;
 19  /

Trigger created.

SQL> connect test/test
Connected.
SQL> create table mytab(id number primary key, a varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytab (a) values ('a');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From mytab;

        ID A
---------- -
         1 a


SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

p.s. no need to do

```
SELECT ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME INTO TABLE_NAME FROM DUAL;
```

just paste it into the command.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ID_TABLE_GEN
  BEFORE INSERT ON APPROOT.' || ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME ||
```