# Trigger to generate customer code

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with fields customer_code and customer_Name.
I wanted to fire a trigger to generate and update a customercode when I insert a customer name.

CustomerCode must be first, third and last letter of customer name and, if there are multiple customers having same name,
code must be added with 1,2,3....etc(eg: RAHAN-RHN, RAHAN-RHN1, RHN2...etc).

Another thing is , if there is another name *(eg: ROHAN-code must be RHN3)
*I am stuck on this part

Can someone please help me how to script a trigger.

Thanks

This is one I created, but there is  error on the second try part, as i mentioned above.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[alphaNumericCustomerReference]
ON [dbo].[CUSTOMER_MASTER]
AFTER INSERT

AS  
declare @NewCode nvarchar(50)
declare @NewName nvarchar(50)
declare @checkCode nvarchar(50)
declare @ExtendedRefCode nvarchar(50)
declare @id int,@msg varchar(200)
declare @sameCustomerCount int

select @id= CUST_ID from inserted i;
select @NewCode= UPPER(SUBSTRING(CUST_NAME, 1, 1)+SUBSTRING(CUST_NAME, 3, 1)+RIGHT(CUST_NAME,1)) from inserted i;
select @checkCode=CUST_CODE from dbo.CUSTOMER_MASTER where CUST_CODE=@NewCode
select @NewName=CUST_NAME from inserted i;
select @sameCustomerCount=count(CUST_NAME)-2 from dbo.CUSTOMER_MASTER where CUST_NAME=@NewName
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
if @checkCode is null 
    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE CUSTOMER_MASTER 
        SET CUST_CODE= @NewCode
        where CUST_ID=@id
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Error occured that is'
        set @msg=(SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())
        print @msg;
    END CATCH
else
    BEGIN TRY
         select @sameCustomerCount=@sameCustomerCount+1;
         select @ExtendedRefCode=@NewCode+convert(nvarchar(255),@sameCustomerCount)
         UPDATE CUSTOMER_MASTER 
         SET CUST_CODE= @ExtendedRefCode
         where CUST_ID=@id
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Error occured that is'
        set @msg=(SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())
        print @msg;
    END CATCH
```

Comment: You shoud have tried to write a trigger yourself before asking for help.

Comment: Look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252244/creating-a-trigger-generating-id-column-value-before-insert-when-new-tables-is-c

Comment: Thanks, I am trying..

Comment: Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s  sorry, its SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @id= CUST_ID from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s could you please show me an example ?

Comment: Just search for "SQL Server trigger" and you'll find ***tons*** of examples - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268247/sql-server-2008-trigger or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372794/simple-t-sql-instead-of-trigger/15373671#15373671 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064311/use-a-trigger-in-sql-server-2008-r2-to-change-the-value-of-one-column-based-on-t or http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/5032/trigger#t=201610241632532725152

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but maybe it will be useful to you.